# operator.setitem problem in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem when using operator.setitem in python 3.

When I use the code below and run it in python 3.1.

```
people=(('fred','sam','jane','betty'),(1,2,3,4))
p_dict = {}
map(operator.setitem, [p_dict]*len(people[0]), people[0],people[1])
print (p_dict)

>>> {}
```

That just prints out a empty dictionary {}.

But I use the same code to run in python 2.6.
It prints out {'jane': 3, 'betty': 4, 'sam': 2, 'fred': 1} . 
This is the result I want.

So, can anyone tell me what's the problem when I run this code in python 3?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It took me several minutes to figure out what that code did, and I needed a Python console. You get the price of most obfuscated code today. And remember, that is a BAD thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a very unpythonesque way to do it. This is much better (and more efficient):

```
people = (('fred','sam','jane','betty'), (1,2,3,4))
p_dict = dict(zip(*people))
```

Works on 2.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the map() is never 'executed'. In Python 3, map just returns an iterator - the individual elements are only computed when they are needed. To work around that, you might write

```
list(map(operator.setitem, [p_dict]*len(people[0]), people[0],people[1]))
```

However, I agree with everybody else that you shouldn't be using map in the first place - as you don't really need to result of the map application.

Comment: Better to use `any` than `list` -- it doesn't accumulate values, and will exhaust the iterator as `setitem` always returns `None`.

Comment: That's a good idea. I still stand by my original claim that using map() is already inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, the result of `map` is lazy which can give you headache when debugging stuff that worked flawlessly in older versions of Python. In other words, it is a generator, so you have to consume it in order to set the items in your dictionary.

You should rather do this with a for loop in this case:

```
people=(('fred','sam','jane','betty'),(1,2,3,4))
p_dict = {}
for key, value in zip(*people):
    p_dict[key] = value
# Now p_dict is {'jane': 3, 'betty': 4, 'sam': 2, 'fred': 1}
```

or with a simple dict constructor: `dict(zip(*people))`.